# How to add some functionality in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I am developing a password manager application and want to add some functionality in it but I don't know how to do it.

I have added 2 option in my app settings i.e.

1. Auto lock when not in use: where I am giving user so select some time like when user doesn't interact with application then my app would be automatically lock after that time, I have added 5 options from which user can select 1. off 2. 30 sec 3. 1 min 4. 5 min 5. 30 min and I have a widget for lockscreen that should be call to lock the application.
2. Activate Auto locking: when user enabled this option, app will lock in 5 seconds after screen goes off.

How can I achieve this functionality in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
void main() {
  runApp(Root());
}

class Root extends StatefulWidget {

  bool _isLocked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: showLockScreen ? LockScreenWidget() : OpenScreenWidget();
    );
  }

  void triggerLock() {
    setState(() {
       isLocked = !isLocked;
    });
   }
}
```

This could be your starter code, but it requires a Timer that you need to implement.
Whenever you want to lock the screen, you can just call triggerLock().

Comment: But how to restart timer everytime user interact with app?

Comment: Give the timer a value that is based on a variable. As soon as this one changes, the timer restarts with the new value.

Comment: But how can I know that user touch the screen? There is any listener or something else?

Comment: Just wrap your screen inside of a `GestureDetector(onTap: ..., child: ....)`.